# changing a word surrounded by numbers using re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I want to change `"to"` to `"-"` only when it is surrounded by numbers or numbers and spaces e.g. `34to55` or `34 to 55` both to be changed to `34-55`. Also, I don't want to change it when the word begins or ends with alphabets e.g. `abc34to55def`

I tried

```
re.sub(?<![a-z])(\d)to(\d)(?!\[a-z]), \\1-\\2, 34to55)
```

but it doesn't give me what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups with word boundaries and use the groups in the replacement.

```
\b(\d+)\s*to\s*(\d+)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `\s*to\s*` Match `to` between optional whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ digits
- `\b` A word boundary

and replace with

```
\1-\2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hdFuFi/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IyvA4D)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\b(\d+)\s*to\s*(\d+)\b"
s = ("34to55 or 34 to 55\n"
    "abc34to55def")
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1-\2", s)
 
if result:
    print (result)
```

Result

```
34-55 or 34-55
abc34to55def
```